# Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Mvc when trying to use endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am building a WebApi endpoint and I have tested it locally and it works well. I have installed it on a server and pointed another service at it, but when it tries to send a request I get a runtime error. When I check the Event Viewer that my endpoint is on I found this error:

```
Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
Exception message: The pre-application start initialization method PreAppStart on type Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineFix threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineFix.PreAppStart()
```

I have tried changing the version number in the web.config and have even tried making a reference directory that isnt managed by nuget to hold the System.Web.Mvc.dll but that didnt work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like somehow when I am building the solution to put it on the server the System.Web.Mvc is not copied into the bin where the solution is  expecting it. Now I am looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue ended up being that the "missing" dlls were missing because the were not getting copied into the bin folder when the release build was occuring. I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/283818/iis-7-cant-run-asp-net-mvc-application-due-to-missing-system-web-helpers) related question and I used suggestions from the answer.

TLDR; basically how I fixed it was to manually copy in each dll as it said it was missing and keep track of the ones you had to move; in my case it was 4 dlls.

After it is not throwing the same "Missing" exception go through the project references dropdown and in the properties tab find the line that says "Copy Local" and set that to True for each missing reference.

To verify it did what was expected, right-click on the project and click unload. Then right click on the project again and edit the csproj file. Find your missing references and under the "Hint path" make sure it has a `<Private>True</Private>` field. Reload the project, make sure it builds then try the release build again and the dlls should now be in the bin folder.

Comment: Here is a similar solution http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/